# PHP: How to recursively resolve DI dependencies?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

What is the easiest way to recursively resolve dependency container dependencies? I'm trying to build my own DI container and are stuck at this stage.

Comment: Use a registry or global variables.

Comment: @Petah I doubt you understand what dependency injection really is, based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are so many great DI containers already out there - if you cannot resist creating your own, they actually will help you get the idea.

Look at [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/), and the DI containers of Symfony 2 and Zend Framework 2, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own IOC container, for the fun of it, with the aim to be the smallest/fastest/most volatile container out there (https://github.com/niclaslindberg/webx-ioc/).

There is not a lot of magic in finding your recursive strategy since your classes/interfaces already depend on each other in a natural order. Simply follow the dependency chain and you'll get it all right.